# Cannot save cookies or use a db, need to display a message only once

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm developing for a pre built php based system.

For restrains that I cannot explain, I cannot use any cookies, sessions or a db link.

I need to display a message only once to every visitor that comes in.

Any creative ideas you guys can think of?

Thanks,

Comment: So you essentially want to be able to save a state without being able to save a state?

Comment: Explain those reasons. They'll probably rule out most of the (much less reliable then the ones you've listed already) alternatives.

Comment: This is not related with creativity, this is related with impossibility.

Comment: @Quentin, @George, The system is pre built, it's old and it uses optimization in a way that the files that I can edit are not the first files that are loaded to the user, so I can't use sessions as the session_start needs to be the first line. Cookies are just not working properly for some reason, I can post the code snippet I'm using but it's just not working. all mysql commands are disabled. Not sure why I am being downvoted.

Comment: @eyazici - for example, I saw an app once that saves data to a txt file, so basically like a db, but on an actual file. that's one solution I could have used if I could write files :) So it's not necessarily impossible.

Comment: no db, no cookies, no sessions... this is going to be an interesting site

Comment: @yi_H the site uses cookies, sessions and a db. However I don't have permissions to use these features.

Comment: @jeroen - there are non-empty lines being sent before though.

Comment: @Or W If the site already uses sessions (your comments seem to contradict themselves...), it´s just plain stupid not to use them for this.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas

1. Use browser's localStorage
2. Pass the message using post or on querystring. Not safe option
3. Use flash store. Same as #1 but don't need flash!
4. Use file disk but then you need to be able to remember who owns the file since multiple people would be on the same server. Without using cookies, I am not sure how to do this.

I personally like using localStorage. First page would create some javascript that stores a message on browser's storage and then second request would pull that message and display it.

Answer (score 0):

While your restraints are somewhat curious I suppose you can add a value in your `$_GET`.

If a visitor visits `www.yoursite.com/` they will see your message, all links displayed on that page include a `$_GET` var 'displayed' or however you wish to name it. so links will be like `www.yoursite.com/page.html?displayed=1`

Then you check

```
if (isset($_GET["displayed"]))
// don't display message
else 
// display message
```

Not a very 'nice' approach, but it would work.

Answer (score 0):

What about using IP Tracking and a flat file or csv. Something similar to that will display it only once per IP.

Comment: But what if the user is behind a router. Most universities are one ip address.

Answer (score 0):

You can force PHP to pre-pend some of your own PHP code, including a session_start() call, with the [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) .ini option.

This guarantees that whatever file you prepend is THE first thing executed in each script.

After that point, you've got a session (or even just a cookie) in which you can store your flags to hide that message on subsequent visits.

Comment: If he doesn't have access to db, cookies, and php sessions, then I doubt he has access to ini or .htaccess files. I could be wrong though